# Python django how to properly test if a queryset returned a result

Tags: python, django

I haven't had a very thorough training in python and sometimes don't know the *correct* way of doing things. One of these things is testing if my resultQuery returned a result or not. I find myself doing this a lot:

```
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except DoesNotExist:
        user = User()
```

I don't know about python but try catches in other languages are supposed to be for exceptions and not for normal program flow. How would you do this with an if else?
I guess I want something similar to:

```
if request.GET.get('email','') is not None:
    email = request.GET['email'])
```

Comment: I've seen the original pattern in other ORMs besides Django's, I wouldn't really sweat it. Handling an exceptional situation needn't necessarily be "bail and report the error". Otherwise, you could do `if len(User.objects.filter(email=email)) == 1: ...`.

Comment: Also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: For this specific case, I would go with `get_or_create` since is shorter, but generally speaking, jro answer is the way to go.

Comment: `get` is an all-or-nothing implementation to directly retrieve a Model-instance. In case of *nothing* a DoesNotExist Exception. It is very different from a query using `filter` and a resulting QuerySet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception example is most commonly the preferred way to do things. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions) has quite a nice description about this:

> Python style calls for the use of exceptions whenever an error
>   condition might arise. Rather than testing for access to a file or
>   resource before actually using it, it is conventional in Python to
>   just go ahead and try to use it, catching the exception if access is
>   rejected.
>
> Exceptions are often used as an alternative to the if-block
>   (...). A commonly-invoked motto is EAFP, or "It is Easier to Ask
>   for Forgiveness than Permission."

Exceptions aren't necessarily costly in Python. Again, quoting the Wikipedia example:

```
if hasattr(spam, 'eggs'):
    ham = spam.eggs
else:
    handle_error()
```

... versus:

```
try:
    ham = spam.eggs
except AttributeError:
    handle_error()
```

These two code samples have the same effect, although there will be performance differences. When spam has the attribute eggs, the EAFP sample will run faster. When spam does not have the attribute eggs (the "exceptional" case), the EAFP sample will run slower.

Specifically for Django, I would use the exception example. It is the standard way to do things in that framework, and following standards is never a bad thing :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` instead of `.get()`, and also make use of django's optimized queryset evaluation.

You can do

```
qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
if qs :
    user = qs[0]
...
```

Comment: I would just like to add, that the return of get and filter are instances of different classes, important when it comes to selecting -related entries or exporting values...

Answer (score 0):

Django defines a class `EmptyQuerySet` that can be used for special implementations when strict `isinstance(...)` testing is necessary.

A straightforward way is as follows:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    if  user:
        # ...
    else:
        # ...

except DoesNotExist:
    user = User()
```

Django provides a `get` method to directly retrieve one single Model instance or will raise an Exception. In this case the normal way is to check for Exceptions such as `DoesNotExist`

To retrieve entire rows from a database query as you normally would, use the `user.objects.filter(...)` method. The returned `QuerySet` instance provides you with `.count()`, `.exists()` methods.

Comment: Note that the `count` and `exists` methods make a database call, so if you already have the queryset results in memory `len` is faster than `count`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that catching the exception is the normal pattern here.  If you do need to check for whether or not a queryset returns results, the [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method is one way to do so that I don't think has been mentioned yet.  The docs run through the various performance implications, most notably that if you know the queryset will be evaluated it's better to just check the boolean interpretation of the queryset.